# MySQL Cluster - When rebooting a data node machine on a 4 machine cluster it hangs SQL nodes

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing

I have a MySQL Cluster with four machines such as (example Ip's):

```
[ndbd(NDB)] 2 node(s) 
id=1    @1.1.1.1 (mysql-5.6.23 ndb-7.4.5, Nodegroup: 0)
id=2    @1.1.1.2 (mysql-5.6.23 ndb-7.4.5, Nodegroup: 0, *)

[ndb_mgmd(MGM)] 2 node(s)
id=49   @1.1.1.51 (mysql-5.6.23 ndb-7.4.5)
id=52   @1.1.1.52 (mysql-5.6.23 ndb-7.4.5)

[mysqld(API)]   3 node(s)
id=50 (not connected, accepting connect from 1.1.1.51)
id=55   @1.1.1.51 (mysql-5.6.23 ndb-7.4.5)
id=56   @1.1.1.52 (mysql-5.6.23 ndb-7.4.5)
```

If I do a cold reboot on either data node machine (id=1 or id=2) then I cannot run any SQL queries (on nodes 55 or 56) until the data node machine comes back online from the reboot. Here are some errors:

ERROR 1297 (HY000): Got temporary error 4028 'Node failure caused abort of transaction' from NDBCLUSTER

ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

If I stop the data node first in ndb_mgm such as 1 Stop or 2 Stop and then reboot the machine then there is no issue.

Is this the correct behavior? If a data node machine crashes or someone pulls the plug on it will the cluster be inoperable (unable to issue SQL commands) until the data node machine comes back online? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!